# Pergunta sem respostas

Tags: debate, suporte

Realizei uma pergunta sobre um tema técnico e como é natural mantive e minha pesquisa sobre o assunto enquanto aguardava respostas da comunidade.

Nunca recebi qualquer resposta pelo que na minha pesquisa tentei várias abordagens ao problema e uma delas me pareceu adequada e nesse sentido actualizei a minha pergunta.

Mantenho-me sem qualquer respostas até ao dia de hoje e considero que não consegui até ao momento uma solução satisfatória.

*A minha pergunta é*: Considerando que se trata de um tema relevante e bem prático e sendo que a minha pergunta não teve até hoje qualquer resposta devo ou não apagar a mesma?

A pergunta a que me refiro é:

[Projecto Netbeans com repositório git e Composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53337/projecto-netbeans-com-reposit%C3%B3rio-git-e-composer)

Comment: Deixa ficar a pergunta. Oferece uma recompensa, pode ser que alguém te consiga responder.

Comment: @JorgeB. tá certo... como funciona as recompensas?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2621/como-ofere%C3%A7o-recompensa-para-uma-pergunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não apague sua pergunta, mesmo que respondida por você mesmo. Isso aconteceu também comigo algumas vezes, e isso não é ruim, afinal, o que vier primeiro a solucionar o problema é o que importa. Uma coisa que deve ter em mente é que responder suas próprias perguntas gera uma documentação sobre o problema; independente de quem tenha respondido o fato é que ela foi, e poderá servir de ajuda para outra pessoa no futuro, assim ela não precisará repetir o mesmo processo que você.

**Alguns casos que respondi minhas dúvidas:**

- [ZF2 changing my expression and returning error (Postgre, Distinct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944447/zf2-changing-my-expression-and-returning-error-postgre-distinct/29945161)
- [jQuery.parseJSON and HTTP Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826157/jquery-parsejson-and-http-status)

Mesmo que outra pessoa não tenha as respondido, caso haja algum problema parecido no futuro com outra pessoa e ela venha a pesquisar minha resposta poderá ser útil para era. O valor das respostas não existe apenas para as pessoas que iniciam os tópicos. Em incontáveis momentos encontrei em tópicos de outras pessoas soluções para os meus problemas, independente do autor da resposta ser o autor do tópico ou não.

E **caso ninguém tenha respondido ainda**, e você continua insatisfeito, o melhor a ser feito é de fato oferecer uma recompensa para quem responder sua pergunta, assim, será conveniente para as pessoas que buscam "popularidade" te ajudar.

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta... entretanto já respondi à minha pergunta...tendo indo de encontro à sua resposta aqui indicada. mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: @chambelix ao menos agora sua pergunta não está mais sem uma resposta. Adeus ironia!! :)

Comment: @Math tem razão. achei uma solução mas mantenho em aberto a soluções melhores para ver se posso dar o assunto como terminado mas até agora nada mesmo.